# In excel, copy separated rows into sequential rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Challenge: In excel, on sheet 1, every 13th row contains results from the preceding 12 rows.  I would like to dynamically copy the results from each 13th row of Sheet 1 to Sheet 2, Rows 1,2,3…, preferably without VBA.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions" - yes, show us the code you already wrote and tell us what exactly is not working. Then we might be able to help. Or, ignore my comment and expect your question to be downvoted and deleted soon by the community. And the system might block further question of yours for some time.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your sheets are named Sheet1, Sheet2, etc, you could use something like this in Cell A1 of sheet2 and then copy and paste down:-

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&ROW()*13)
```

This would give you the value of every 13th row of sheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use INDIRECT. It is volatile and slow.

Don't use ROW. It is susceptible to errors from row deletions and other problems.

Instead use INDEX and ROWS:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROWS($1:1)*13)
```